# Does a Malaysian citizen need a visa to transit through Cochin airport, India, on the way to UAE?

Tags: transit, india, malaysian-citizens

Does a Malaysian passport holder need a visa for transiting for 2 hours and 40 mins at Cochin airport, on the way to United Arab Emirates?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Timatic Database](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html), the common airline industry travel document resource, no visa or transit visa is necessary provided a) the Cochin layover is less than 24 hours, b) the Malaysian passenger is heading for a destination outside India, and c) the passenger remains in the international transit area (that is, "airside") and does not leave the airport.

No visa is therefore required in these circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response... but to be on a safe side, I just applied from the Indian Visa Centre last week. The staff there said, yes I need to apply although the transit is only 2 hour 40 mins. According to them, I need transit visa because change of airlines ;(